# Added cordova to my Angular app and it's slower than app in browser

Tags: angular, cordova, ionic-framework, mobile, rendering

I have project in `Angular 8` and I added `cordova` because I had to prepare it to `publish in AppStore`. Everything works fine but `mobile app` is `rendering` slower than app in `browser`. I guess it's problem with `cordova`. **Do you know how to improve it?** Which `plugins` I need add to make `mobile app` faster? **Thnx**

Answer (score 0):

It's not by adding plugins that your app ll be faster.

Cordova is slower than native app, but speed can be better

In my case, to speed up the app, i had to :

1) Clean your code HTML / JS / CSS

2) Compress your code

3) Minimize the number of request to the server

Note:

Please read this article :

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/cross-platform/tools-for-cordova/tips-workarounds/better-web-performance?view=toolsforcordova-2015

Comment: 1. Done, 2. Done, 3. It's min number of requests and it's still slow. It's big app. I know that it's not the same like in the browser but I guess that it's some way to improve it.

Comment: you can analyse your JS performances with chrome console : https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/rendering-tools

Comment: I should install WKWebView to improve it!